# Error 3 'Text3' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: vb.net, undeclared-identifier

I have this error message:

> Error 3 Text3 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

I am making acalculator. This is `scriptPublic Class Form1`. I work in Visual Basic 2010.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As Single, b As Single, c As Single
    a = text1.text
    b = text2.text
    c = a + b
    Text3.text = c

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The error message should be clear: `Text3` is not declared or it is declared with a protection level that makes it not usable by this code. Either way, we don't have enough context to give you an answer other than to tell you to verify that `Text3` is declared correctly.

Comment: In Form Designer right click the text box (Text3) and click properties to see what is the name there. Replace that with 'Text3'.